# How do I clear an asp:textbox control from a different control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autopostback, web-user-controls

I have a master page that contains two other child pages. It's a web page with a couple tabs contained on it. Each tab has a number of controls inside.

The issue I am having is when a textBox value changes in the first tab, I want it to clear out the text box on the other tab. When the text changes in the textbox in the first tab, it fires an on text changed event.

Inside that event, I find the control on the other tab, and while debugging I can see the value that is currently stored in it. I use `otherTabTextbox.Text = ""` to set the value to be empty and let the post back finish, but when I click to change tabs, the previous value is still in the text box. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you could post sample code of your client and sever side, it would help a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use FinControl method:

```
var textBox1 = tab1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
textBox1.Text = null;
```

If it's not working I guess u have multiple UpdatePanels?

Comment: I have done this, and while debugging I can see the data value change, but when the code is finished executing, I click to the other tab, and the original value is still in the textbox.

Comment: I have an update panel on the first tab, but not the second. I will modify the second tab to have everything in an update panel and get back to you.

Comment: just try to remove it and test yr page or at least make it  UpdateMode="Always"

Comment: @conover2008 could u plz accept my answer if it helped u. tnx